# segmentation fault in running uwsim

Tags: ros, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Earlier uwsim was running well. Now it is showing segmentation error for last 3-4 days ..

```
[ INFO] [1412582441.771043565]: GPSSensor publisher on topic g500/gps
[ INFO] [1412582441.771251203]: DVLSensor publisher on topic g500/dvl
[ INFO] [1412582441.771457584]: VirtualCameraToROSImage publisher on topic /uwsim/rangecamera_info
[ INFO] [1412582441.771843388]: RangeSensorToROSRange publisher on topic /uwsim/g500/range
[ INFO] [1412582441.838518974]: SimDev_Echo_ROSPublisher on topic g500/echo2
[ INFO] [1412582441.839045438]:  MultibeamSensorToROS publisher on topic g500/multibeam
[ INFO] [1412582441.839233172]: SimDev_Echo_ROSPublisher on topic g500/echo1
[ INFO] [1412582441.839349458]: ForceSensor_ROSPublisher on topic g500/ForceSensor
[ INFO] [1412582441.844583501]: ForceSensor_ROSPublisher Waiting for physics to be initialized
[ INFO] [1412582442.844989907]: ForceSensor_ROSPublisher Waiting for physics to be initialized
[ INFO] [1412582443.845381929]: ForceSensor_ROSPublisher Waiting for physics to be initialized
[ INFO] [1412582444.845571687]: ForceSensor_ROSPublisher Waiting for physics to be initialized
[ INFO] [1412582445.845772760]: ForceSensor_ROSPublisher Waiting for physics to be initialized
[ INFO] [1412582446.846130836]: ForceSensor_ROSPublisher Waiting for physics to be initialized
/opt/ros/hydro/lib/uwsim/uwsim: line 23:  6185 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) rosrun uwsim uwsim_binary --dataPath ~/.uwsim/data $@
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194249/segmentation-fault-in-running-uwsim/) by [Mind_hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/19892/mind_hunter/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2014-10-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) on 2014-10-06**:
I think we need more information in order to help you. Have you tried running it with --disableShaders ?, Issue started after an update of kernel / drivers ?, if the crash is at starting uwsim, it usually means a graphics/driver problem.

**Comment by [Mind_hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/19892/mind_hunter/) on 2014-10-07**:
I tried with --disableShaders  but it didnt work. I did not update kernel but i think i updated drivers. Is that the reason?Actually i reinstalled xserver-xorg and then reconfigured it .. Also i upgraded the packages.

**Comment by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) on 2014-10-07**:
It seems the crash happens at window initialization, and if it started with a xserver reinstall I would say it is a drivers issue. Make sure you have 3d support and check your graphic drivers are working as they should.

**Comment by [Mind_hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/19892/mind_hunter/) on 2014-10-07**:
Ok now it is working . i have reinstalled xserver-xorg and now it is working fine..Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried a `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` ?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mind_hunter](https://answers.ros.org/users/19892/mind_hunter/) on 2014-10-07**:
no . i only used sudo apt-get upgrade